# Jekyll, file not found

Tags: javascript, html, csv, path, jekyll

I'm trying to convert a CSV file to HTML in a `Jekyll` website table using [this code](https://bl.ocks.org/ndarville/7075823)

I put the code in a `.md` page file.

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 d3.text("/_data/my_file.csv", function(data) {
 ...
 ...
 ...
 });
</script>
```

When I launch `bundle exec jekyll serve`, console says

> ERROR `/website/_data/my_file.csv' not found.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 d3.text("{{ site.data.my_file }}", function(data) {
 ...
 ...
 ...
 });
</script>
```

Source: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles/